# When a textinput focuses, how to avoid pushing a view up and overlay it instead?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Here is a simple gist of the app.js to reproduce the issue

[Code example](https://gist.github.com/rtman/55a41ba58782c57425e035a11179fd5a)

I have a screen where there is a `FlatList` sandwiched between a Header and a Footer component. The FlatList has rows that when clicked turn into `TextInputs`. `Flatlist` handles the keyboard in this screen just fine, by scrolling up the clicked row so that it is just above the keyboard.

The problem is that the Footer component is brought up above the keyboard instead of being covered. It is unnecessary to see the footer when editing the text fields and in the actual use case the header and footer are much larger so it seriously limits the available screen real estate. It basically squishes the textinput into a tiny row that is barely useable.

TextInput UnFocused

[image: TextInput UnFocused]

TextInput Focused (Note the Footer is pushed up)

[image: TextInput Focused (Note the Footer is pushed up)]

How can I get the Keyboard to overlay over the Footer while keeping the TextInputs keyboard aware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround until I find the proper answer, if it exists :(, I decided to attach keyboard listeners and conditionally render the footer. So basically if the keyboard is closed the footer is rendered if not the footer is not rendered. It works fairly well, there's a graphical flicker as it goes from rendered to not rendered which isn't the best but its better than the unusable alternative that I had. I might be able to find some way to smooth that out at some point.

A bit of a hack but works for now!

Note: The keyboard listeners don't work with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` but they do for `adjustResize` which is what I need to use anyways.

Here is the modified parts of code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      showFooter: true
    }
  }

  RenderFooter(){
    if(this.state.showFooter){
      return(
         <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>
            Footer
          </Text>
        </View>
      )
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
      this.keyboardDidShowSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this.keyboardDidShow);
      this.keyboardDidHideSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this.keyboardDidHide);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowSub.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideSub.remove();
  }

  keyboardDidShow = (event) => {
    console.log('keyboardDidShow')
    this.setState({
      showFooter: false
    })
  };

  keyboardDidHide = (event) => {
    console.log('keyboardDidHide')
    this.setState({
      showFooter: true
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View  style={styles.container}>
        {this.RenderHeader()}
          <FlatList
              data={data}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                  <ListItem
                    item = {item}/>
              )}
              extraData={this.state}
              keyExtractor={item => item.name}/>
        {this.RenderFooter()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I don't  see tyhis as a correct answer, I have a footer that contaisn the textinput itself, so this is not the solution, you just changed somehow the logic of your app to fix the problem, but Good for you! but it is not the correct answer!

Comment: use scrollview in parent

Answer (score 0):

In Android, our layout will be auto resize if keyboard show up, it's not happen in IOS.

To fix this, you could change `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` to `adjustNothing`

Comment: While setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` does overlay the keyboard over the footer. It disables keyboard awareness for the `TextInputs` within the `FlatList`. Also this disables keyboard awareness throughout the app. So this solution doesn't work for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ScrollView in Parent, but make it bounded by view of fixed height and width, so it appears as static screen and not scrollview,

Inside Scrollview, you might be having flatlist + Textinput

Also bound flatlist to a height

ScrollView - height 100% but fixed, should not scroll
Flatlist - 80% height
TextInput - 20% height